# Visual Studio for Mac: web reference could not be added

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, wsdl, .net-core, visual-studio-mac

I want to add a web service reference following the steps:

1. Right-click on a project
2. Add web reference
3. Paste WSDL endpoint

But when I click on 'OK' button

> **The web reference could not be added:**
>   DotNetProject_Modified' must be called on the foreground thread.

I have the following configurations:

Visual Studio for Mac:

Version:
7.5 (build 1254)

**NuGet
  Version:** 4.3.1.4445

**.NET Core**

Runtime Versions:
    2.0.5
    2.0.0

The complete error log:

```
    ERROR [2018-05-12 14:00:46Z]: The web reference could not be added
System.InvalidOperationException: 'DotNetProject_Modified' must be called on the foreground thread.
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.ForegroundDispatcher.AssertForegroundThread (System.String caller) [0x0001f] in C:\BuildAgent\work\9f4c49cb464f2a60\src\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.Workspaces\ForegroundDispatcher.cs:24 
  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Mac.LanguageServices.Razor.ProjectSystem.RazorProjectHostBase.DotNetProject_Modified (System.Object sender, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItemModifiedEventArgs args) [0x0000e] in C:\BuildAgent\work\9f4c49cb464f2a60\src\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Mac.LanguageServices.Razor\ProjectSystem\RazorProjectHostBase.cs:124 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void_object_SolutionItemModifiedEventArgs(object,MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItemModifiedEventArgs)
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionFolderItem.OnModified (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItemModifiedEventArgs args) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/SolutionFolderItem.cs:452 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Project.OnModified (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItemModifiedEventArgs args) [0x0001a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/Project.cs:408 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionFolderItem.NotifyModified (System.String hint) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/SolutionFolderItem.cs:439 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Project.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00075] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/Project.cs:2337 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.DotNetProject.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00030] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/DotNetProject.cs:1767 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Project+DefaultMSBuildProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/Project.cs:4636 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectExtension.cs:266 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectExtension.cs:266 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectExtension.cs:266 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectExtension.cs:266 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectExtension.cs:266 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectExtension.cs:266 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectExtension.cs:266 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectExtension.cs:266 
  at MonoDevelop.DotNetCore.DotNetCoreProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00019] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.DotNetCore/MonoDevelop.DotNetCore/DotNetCoreProjectExtension.cs:616 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectExtension.cs:266 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectExtension.cs:266 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectExtension.cs:266 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectExtension.cs:266 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectExtension.OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectExtension.cs:266 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Project.NotifyItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] objs) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/Project.cs:2315 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectItemCollection`1[T].NotifyAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] items, System.Boolean comesFromParent) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectItemCollection.cs:150 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ProjectItemCollection`1[T].OnItemsAdded (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] items) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ProjectItemCollection.cs:98 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.ItemCollection`1[T].Add (T item) [0x00018] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/ItemCollection.cs:66 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.WS.WebServiceDiscoveryResultWS+<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<GenerateDescriptionFiles>b__0 () [0x0005a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.WebReferences/MonoDevelop.WebReferences.WS/WebServiceDiscoveryResultWS.cs:94 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs:680 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2509 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.WS.WebServiceDiscoveryResultWS+<GenerateDescriptionFiles>d__8.MoveNext () [0x000b0] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.WebReferences/MonoDevelop.WebReferences.WS/WebServiceDiscoveryResultWS.cs:89 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.WebServiceDiscoveryResult+<GenerateFiles>d__13.MoveNext () [0x000f7] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.WebReferences/MonoDevelop.WebReferences/WebServiceDiscoveryResult.cs:94 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2017-12/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at MonoDevelop.WebReferences.Commands.WebReferenceCommandHandler+<NewWebReference>d__1.MoveNext () [0x00158] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5965/498923ea/source/monodevelop/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.WebReferences/MonoDevelop.WebReferences.Commands/WebReferenceCommandHandler.cs:49 
2018-05-12 14:02:39.693 VisualStudio[456:3934] customMenuItemViewMouseMoved: GetEventParameter(kEventParamWindowRef) failed: -9870
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce this. What sort of project are you adding the web reference to? Can you also attach the IDE log (Help - Open Log Directory) after reproducing the error?

Comment: @MattWard I have already edited the question with the logs, BTW this errors start when I updated at last version of visual studio

Comment: Thanks. I suspect the web service I am using is not causing the same code to be run. This looks to be a bug in the web service addin, which seems to have existed in the older version of Visual Studio for Mac 7.4, and is being flagged by the web tools addin which seems to be checking the thread is the expected one. You may be able to work around this by using the older Visual Studio for Mac 7.4 or by temporarily disabling the web tools addin.

Comment: OK thanks to the callstack I can reproduce it now. If you have open a project that contains any .cshtml files and then try to add a web reference the problem occurs. I was trying a C# console project.

Comment: Opened a bug for this on GitHub - https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/issues/4784

Comment: Sure, I have tried a console project and I had used on my web project, works correctly, thank you!